# nested exception is NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [com.springfoundation.service.SecurityService]

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

When I launch my application I get this error in my stacktrace

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [com.springfoundation.service.SecurityService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations:
```

this is the code I have in my spring security class.java

```
public interface SecurityService {
    String findLoggedInUsername();
    void autologin(String username, String password);
    }
```

this is the code I have of the interface implementer

```
public class SecurityServiceImpl implements SecurityService {

     @Autowired
        private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

        @Autowired
        private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

        private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SecurityServiceImpl.class);

        @Override
        public String findLoggedInUsername() {
            Object userDetails = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getDetails();
            if (userDetails instanceof UserDetails) {
                return ((UserDetails)userDetails).getUsername();
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public void autologin(String username, String password) {
            UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);
            UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, password, userDetails.getAuthorities());

            authenticationManager.authenticate(usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken);

            if (usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.isAuthenticated()) {
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken);
                logger.debug(String.format("Auto login %s successfully!", username));
            }
        }
```

the code in my contoller is shown below making use of the Spring security class I stated above

```
@Controller
public class UserController {
    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;
    @Autowired
    private SecurityService securityService;
```

I am using the above declaration to a mapping still inside the controller class

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/registration", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String registration(@ModelAttribute("userForm") User userForm, BindingResult bindingResult, Model model) {
        userValidator.validate(userForm, bindingResult);

        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            return "registration";
        }

        userService.save(userForm);

       securityService.autologin(userForm.getUsername(), userForm.getPasswordConfirm());

        return "redirect:/welcome";
    }
```

this is the complete stacktrace of my issue that I am currently facing

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private 
com.springfoundation.service.SecurityService com.springfoundation.controller.UserController.securityService; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type 
[com.springfoundation.service.SecurityService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies 
as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:513) ~[spring-beans-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:92) ~[spring-beans-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:284) ~[spring-beans-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
    ... 22 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [com.springfoundation.service.SecurityService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

Please what could be wrong that my code is showing the above error

Comment: SecurityServiceImpl is not annotated with `@Component` (or `@Service`), so it's not a Spring bean.

Comment: Actually I have it in my code, @Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

Comment: The error is hidden in what you haven't posted: what is the package being scanned? What is the package of your implementation. Does it extend the correct interface?

Comment: <context:component-scan base-package="com.springfoundation.*"/>

Comment: @Blaze Post your xml config, preferable it's posted complete.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added `@ComponentScan("com.your.securityservice.package")` to your config java/xml config file? If you haven't yet, the Spring container won't recognize the service's annotations.

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace? With what you've supplied, nothing could have gone wrong.

Comment: I commented out the Autowired in the controller class and it worked. Is it reasonable like this >>>>>>>>>>   //@Autowired
    private SecurityService securityService;

Comment: check to see detailed stacktrace

Comment: The error message isn't long enough for me to say with 100% certainty, but I would assume that the underlying issue is with the wiring in your `SecurityServiceImpl` class. Check to make sure that your  `UserDetailsService` is wired/annotated properly.

Comment: Everything is properly done. Which more stacktrace do you need